# Performance repercussions of execute in webdriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver, webdriver-io

I was unable to find any information on this, so curious if anyone has done the performance testing of `execute()` calls from a test. It's my understanding that these inject the javascript into the current frame, execute it, and return the result.

Is it better to:
a) Run a bunch of smaller execute calls
b) Run as few as possible, but the calls themselves do a lot more

My specific case is using WebDriverIO and I need to run these in order to gather debug information available in the application, or interact with local/session storage. So this means I could:

a) Wrap each desired property in a getter that performs an execute, and always returns an up-to-date property that reflects the current state of the application. This would result in 5x the amount of `execute()` calls that run, but they would be very small.

b) Bunch all of the desired properties into one giant call, and call it whenever the application's state changes. This is what I'm currently doing, but it requires "refreshing" our test properties often. If a test author forgets to do this, they will have bad data.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed of the `execute` function is mostly dependent on the network latency.  I ran some tests in a "local network" scenario (via [Spectron](https://electronjs.org/spectron)), and found the `execute` overhead was usually only `10`~`15`ms.

So, if you're using a local network too, I'd recommend going down the "best code quality" route, since you can gather a hundred properties in a second.
If you're in a "remote networK" scenario (eg. [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/)), you might consider "batching" the requests, to improve speed.

For reference, here's what I tested:

- Performing 1000 client-side tasks via a single `execute`: `408ms`
- Performing 1000 client-side tasks via 1000 `execute` calls: `10347ms` (added `10ms` per task)

Comment: What's up Scott?